# Where does loader loads image?

Tags: windows

I am trying to understand OS memory management by reading windows internals and some other tutorials in net but get confused on the topic. My doubts are, On what basis the OS allocate space in RAM for a process? When the OS allocate virtual memory for the process? Where the loader first loads image, into RAM or into the virtual memory?

Comment: The OS only allocates space in the paging file, just a reservation.  RAM is dynamically allocated when the code in the process trips a paging fault, caused by addressing a memory location that isn't mapped yet.  The loader merely sets up the paging table entries to map executable file content into the address space.  Such data or code is also page-faulted into RAM.  The paging file is used when RAM pages have to get unmapped again because RAM is needed elsewhere and the page isn't backed by the executable file.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, first it creates the dummy file(Thunblines) in Ram means it get loads into the RAM and immediately shows on the screen. that's how the RAM works.
and when you want to perform any actions(Delete or move or any), it deals with the actual storage space.

hope you understand a bit... thanks